# Get Images Products

Tags: magento

i need get the all images of one product.

i tried this:

```
<?php $_images = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId())->getMediaGalleryImages(); ?>
```

and he gave the images in the variable $_images, but i don´t know how access this variable.

when i see the variable:

```
Varien_Data_Collection Object(
    [_items:protected] =&gt; Array(
        [36] =&gt; Varien_Object Object(
            [_data:protected] =&gt; Array(
               [url] =&gt; http://blabla.com.br/blabla/media/catalog/product/1/3/133.jpg
```

and i need this url, but i don't know to get her

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use like below

```
<?$_images = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId())->getMediaGalleryImages();?>
<?if($_images){?>           
   <?$i=0; foreach($_images as $_image){ $i++;?>
      <a href="#"><img src="<?=$this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'thumbnail', $_image->getFile())->resize(200, 130); ?>" width="200" height="130" alt="<?=$this->htmlEscape($_image->getLabel());?>" title="<?=$this->htmlEscape($_image->getLabel());?>" /></a>              
   <?}?>
<?}?>
```

hope this will sure work for you,

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
foreach ($_images as $image){
    echo $image->getUrl().'<br />';
}
```

Comment: he worked :D
have possibility of i use the resize of magento here:

foreach...
    img[] = image->getUrl

<img src="echo img[1]"  <<<---- HERE???

Comment: if you want a resized version of the image check the answer from @liyakat. It should get you what you need.